# Learning my way thru ASP.Net 4 basic web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to learn asp.net 4 web app but playing around the web page template shipped in VS 2010.

I clicked New Project --> (Web) ASP.Net Web Application
I click ok.
So now I am trying to manipulate the color of the blue header and the font color or the header text. But I am cant do it thru the css.

Any ideas what is going on in the background?

**UPDATE**
This is what I get in design time:
[image: DesignTime]

This is what I get at runtime:

[image]

Comment: are you running with VS web server, or IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your changes aren't being reflected, try:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>
- Perhaps clear your browser cache?
- Try another browser
- If Internet Explorer, ensure your browser is checking for new versions '[Every time I visit the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOUE.png)'
- Publishing to a new IIS directory, rather than Visual Studio's built in web server.
- Ensure there aren't any caching directives.

Comment: I did what you suggested (it's what I was doing before), I can see the font-color changes in design time "split" mode, but not when I run the page.

Comment: @user: this is a big deviation from how the asp.net dev experience should start! Can you publish to a web server and see how it's served or rendered?

Comment: dont have an IIS setup yet. Will work on that and let you know how it goes. Thanks !!

Comment: same result with a web server. (why would a web server give a different result than an VS server? )

Comment: dont know what happened (midnight gremlins) but now the changes are reflected in runtime.